# Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' ....... POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm coding in powershell IDE trying to do a script to generate a AD account. But a confirm parameter that I'm trying to fix for hours is getting out of hands. I've tried to set confirm to false but doesn't seems to fix it.

```
function New-ADAccount {                 <# The function 'New-ADAccount' is declared with the 'param' block defining the function parameters #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (                             
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]   
        [string] $Name,                  <#  Request the Name, String #>

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [string] $GivenName,             <#  Request the GivenName, String  #>

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Surname,               <#  Request the Surname, String  #>

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $SamAccountName,        

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $UserPrincipalName,     

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Path,                  <#  Request the Path  #>
            
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [securestring] $ADAccountPassword, <#  Request the AccountPassword #>

        [Parameter()]
        [bool] $Enabled = $true,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $CountryAcronym = "CA",
        
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Country = "Canada",

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $CountryCode = "124",

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $StreetAddress = "XXXX",

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Province = "Quebec",

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $PostalCode = "XXX XXX",

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $City = "Gatineau"
    )

    try {
        $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SamAccountName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($User) {
            Write-Warning "User '$SamAccountName' already exists."                  <#  Verify if there's duplicate of username account #>       
            return
        }

        $params = @{
            'name'                 = $Name
            'givenName'            = $GivenName
            'sn'                   = $Surname
            'SamAccountName'       = $SamAccountName
            'UserPrincipalName'    = $UserPrincipalName
            'Path'                 = $Path
            'Enabled'              = $Enabled
            'co'                   = $Country
            'c'                    = $CountryAcronym
            'PassThru'             = $true
            'streetAddress'        = $StreetAddress
            'st'                   = $Province
            'l'                    = $City
            'postalCode'           = $PostalCode
            'ADAccountPassword'    = $ADAccountPassword
        }

        $newUser = New-ADUser @params 
        Write-Host "Account '$SamAccountName' created successfully."

        # Set the account password
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $newUser -NewPassword $ADAccountPassword -Reset

        return $newUser
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "An error occurred while creating the account: $_"
    }
}

$ADAccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MySecurePassword123" -AsPlainText -Force

New-ADAccount -Name "Albert Schmidt" -GivenName "Albert" -Surname "Schmidt" -SamAccountName "a.schmidt" -UserPrincipalName "a.schmidt@otc-cta.gc.ca" -Path "OU=USERS,OU=AGENCY,OU=CTAUsers,DC=cta-otc.corp" -ADAccountPassword $ADAccountPassword -Enabled $true
```

This is error message :

```
New-ADAccount : An error occurred while creating the account: Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter 'Confirm'. 
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\Powershell Project\ScriptADautomation.ps1:90 char:1
+ New-ADAccount -Name "Albert Schmidt" -GivenName "Albert" -Surname "Sc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-ADAccount
```

Thank you!

Comment: Only thing wrong I'm seeing is `ADAccountPassword` as a parameter name when `New-ADUser` doesn't have such parameter, the actual parameter name is just `AccountPassword`

Comment: Yeah and it doesn't really fix the problem, it's really not an obvious error

Comment: Are you sure that you loaded (the latest version of) your scrpt? I recommend to start a new PowerShell session and try again...

Comment: Well perhaps your issue comes from trying to use aliases in your splatting hashtable instead of the cmdlet's actual Parameter Names.

Comment: It kinda worked, i fixed the atribute parameter. Now i got this error. New-ADAccount : An error occurred while creating the account: The server is unwilling to process the request
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\Powershell Project\Try n2.ps1:89 char:1
+ New-ADAccount -Name "Albert Schmidt" -GivenName "Albert" -Surname "Sc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-ADAccount